# Why my progress bar append on only last div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar

Here, I have a webpage in which I have so many divs.

All divs have the same id. but there is the type different.

Like the first div have type="timeline" and other is type="slideshow".

When I scroll on my type=timelime div I have progress bar shown on top.
it works very fine but it only appends my progress bar at one div.
 My progress bar only work on when type equals to timeline.

Progress bar move when timeline scroll on this everything work fine but i don't know why it not append all progress bar with type=timeline.

like same I have a slideshow. I have three slideshows only third slideshow work very properly.

Here is my code.

```js
function isOnScreen(that){
 var win = $(window);
 var viewport = {
   top : win.scrollTop(),
   left : win.scrollLeft()
 };
 viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
 viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();
 var bounds = that.offset();
 bounds.right = bounds.left + that.outerWidth();
 bounds.bottom = bounds.top + that.outerHeight();
 return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
   }
   
   $(window).scroll(function() {
  if(isOnScreen($("#slide"))) {
   $("#progressbar").show();
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isOnScreen($("#slide"))) {
     $("#progressbar").show();
     var scroll        = $(this).scrollTop();
     var height        =$('#slide').position().top;
     var percent       = (scroll- height) / 100;
   
     $("#progressbar").attr('value', parseInt(percent*6));
    } 
   });
  } else {
   $("#progressbar").hide();
  }   
 });

 var para = document.createElement("Progress");
 para.setAttribute('id', 'progressbar');
 para.setAttribute('value', 0);
 para.setAttribute('max', 100);
 // document.getElementById("slide").appendChild(para);
 
 $("[type=timeline]").addClass('timelineClass');
 let selectSection = document.querySelectorAll(".timelineClass");
 let selectLength = selectSection.length;

 for(i = 0;i < selectLength; i++){
  let data = selectSection[i].getAttribute('type');
  if(data=='timeline') {
   console.log("inside")
   selectSection[i].appendChild(para);
  }
 }
 
 var divSlide = document.querySelectorAll('#slide');
 var myNodeList = divSlide.length;
 for(var i = 0; i < myNodeList; i++) {
  var type = divSlide[i].getAttribute("type");
  if (type == "timeline") {
  
  } else if (type == "slideshow") {
   var timeline = divSlide[i];         
   let sliderData = timeline.getElementsByTagName("section");
   timeline.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",'<a class="left  color_arrow carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" onclick = "plusDivs(-1, timeline)" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>');

   timeline.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',' <a class="right color_arrows  carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"  onclick = "plusDivs(1, timeline)" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>');

   var slideIndex = 1;
   showDivs(slideIndex, timeline);
  }
 }
 function plusDivs(sliderItem, el) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += sliderItem, el, sliderItem);
 }

 function showDivs(sliderItem, el , dir) {

  let i;
  let sliderData = el.getElementsByTagName("section");
 
  if (sliderItem > sliderData.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (sliderItem < 1) {slideIndex = sliderData.length}

  for (i = 0; i < sliderData.length; i++) {
   sliderData[i].classList.add('hide')
   sliderData[i].classList.remove('active')  
   sliderData[i].classList.remove('animated')  
   sliderData[i].classList.remove('fadeInRight')  
  }

  sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.remove('hide')
  sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.add('active')
  sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.add('animated')
  if(dir === 1)
   sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.add('fadeInLeft')
  else if(dir === -1)
   sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.add('fadeInRight')
 }
```

```css
div[type="timeline/slideshow"] > section , div[type="timeline"] > section  {
 margin: auto;
 width: 900px;
 z-index: 100;
 opacity: 0.5;
 border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
 border-top: 1px solid grey;
 min-height:250px;
 background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin-bottom: 55px;
 position: relative;
 top: 50px;
 box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
 -moz-animation: fadein 2s; 
 -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
 -o-animation: fadein 2s; 
 animation: fadein 2s;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"] > section:hover , div[type="timeline"] > section:hover {
 opacity:1;
} 

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]::before , div[type="timeline"]::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 0;
 width: .2rem;
 background: white;
 height: 55px;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section::after, div[type="timeline"]>section::after  {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: -81px;
 width: .2rem;
 background: grey;
 height: 79px;
}
div[type="timeline/slideshow"] > section> header , div[type="timeline"] > section> header  {
 font-weight: 600;
 color: cadetblue;
 transform: translate(16px, 23px);
 font-size: 34px;
 font-family: arial;
 position: relative;
}
div[type="timeline/slideshow"] > section> article ,div[type="timeline"] > section> article {
 transform: translate(12px,14px);
 color: black;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-family: arial;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}  
div[type="timeline"]>section:last-of-type::after {
 display: none;
}
 
div[type="slideshow"]  {
 height:471px;
}
div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) {
 margin: auto;
 width: 900px;
 z-index: 100;
 border-top: 1px solid grey;
 border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
 min-height:250px;
 background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin-bottom: 55px;
 position: relative;
 top: 21.4%;
 left:200px;
 box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
}

div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) > header {
 font-weight: 600;
 color: cadetblue;
 transform: translate(93px, 32px);
 font-size: 34px;
 font-family: arial;
 position: relative;
}

div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) > article {
 transform: translate(87px,39px);
 color: black;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-family: arial;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

.active{    
 opacity: 1 !important;
}

.hide {
 opacity: 0; 
 min-height: 0 !important; 
 margin: 0 !important;
}
.hide header, .hide article {
 display: none;
}
@keyframes fadein {
 0% { opacity: 0 }
 50% { opacity: 0.5 }
 100% {opacity: 1}
}


progress {
 height: 3.6px;
 top: 46px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: -1px;
 margin-top: -1px;
}
.color_arrow {
 position: relative;
 top: 228px;
 color: #085153;
 left: 93px;
}
.color_arrows {
 position: relative;
 top: 228px;
 color: #085153;
 left: 94% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div type="timeline" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>
<div type="timeline" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>
<div type="timeline" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>
<div type="timeline" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>

<div type="slideshow" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>
<div type="slideshow" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: "_All divs have the same id_", they must not, `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document.

Comment: yes!! I have a restriction to use only this document structure. so is there any chances.

Comment: That's invalid HTML, you should use a class instead of id. If you really can't change the HTML, use `document.querySelectorAll` to collect all the elements with the same id.

Comment: can you please update my code so i understand exactly  what you want to say.

Comment: Ah, you can get the elements with jQuery too, instead of the id selector `#slide`, use attribute selector `[id="slide"]`.

Comment: not working....Everything working fine but it append only last div why.

Comment: Did you replace all of them?

Comment: yes i replace all of them but not working.

Comment: Offtopic: There is a weird mix of jquery and js in here. Either use one or the other, yet mixing jquery.selector with document.querySelectorAll/getElementsByTagName and .addClass together with .classList is very inconsistent.